# How can I patch 1"- 2" gaps between coved plaster ceilings and new sheetrock walls?

Tags: plaster, patching-drywall

We had to replace some old lath/plaster walls with new sheetrock.  We left the coved portion of the plastered ceiling in place, but where the sheetrock meets the coved ceiling there is a 1" - 2" gap (we left the lath in place in this gap). We have read that using a fiberglass product for these gaps is not recommended (cracks can easily develop).  Paper tape is not wide enough.  How do we properly repair these gaps?

Disclaimer:  We aren't professionals...but want to do a good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one to two inches? How thick were the original plaster walls!?

A picture would probably help. What I'd suggest is bridge the transition from the coving to the wall with some crown moulding.

Comment: Clarification:  The gaps aren't in the thickness of the plaster walls, but in the distance between where the cove ends and the drywall begins.  We cut away the lath/plaster from the walls, leaving the lath in place above the cut line so we would have a solid structure to mud over.  The areas where there is a large gap are where the plaster broke off further than we intended into the coved area.  Unfortunately I don't have the immediate means to take a picture.  Sorry.

Comment: I would also add that we cannot put up crown moulding in this area because it is in the cove of the ceiling...it is a rental house and we don't want to add this expense.

Comment: It's a rental? Shouldn't the landlord be doing this? Anyways, I think I understand...it's a gap between materials rather than a depth issue. Ideally, you'd plaster down to the new sheetrock. Then you can apply a fiberglass tape (which helps PREVENT cracks, rather than creates them) and mud the gap. But that's not the easiest thing to do and it will be tricky to get it to blend well (then again, it's a rental, so maybe not something to worry about).

Comment: Thanks DAO1...we may need to call in an expert to do the job.

Comment: DAO1...we own the rental, and that is why we are investing in this work.   As stated I think you might be right about the trickiness of the blend.  Thanks!

Comment: Would the style of the house tolerate a built up crown moulding? It may not work aesthetically, but one option would be to just roughly plaster the gap, then cover it with a 3"-ish tall picture-rail type moulding so that it butts up to the bottom of the coving. Here's an example I found. It's a coved ceiling with a transition into moulding below. http://www.archwaysandceilings.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/coved-ceiling-finished.png